# Get VPC details through API

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I want to get the list of attached an EC2 to that VPC / auto scaling group. Or List of created EC2 in my AWS account.

Also, Can I get any notification or trigger in case of adding new EC2 in the VPC/ auto-scaling group?

I am trying to track everything in my database to get this but I need to make it all automatic.

Comment: What you you tried and what problems are you experiencing? Which language are you using? Feel free to edit your question with more details. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also, take a look at [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) — it might contain the data you seek.

Comment: Thanks! I want just any way by which I can get EC2 details from AWS account.

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is an easy way to obtain information from an AWS account and to create/modify/delete resources.

See: [ec2 — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/) (Especially the commands that start with *List*.)

Comment: Can we get/download key-pair (PEM file) through the AWS CLI?

Comment: You can create a keypair with [create-key-pair](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-key-pair.html) and you can upload a keypair with [import-key-pair](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/import-key-pair.html). However, for security purposes it is not possible to download a keypair. Instead, you are responsible for keeping and maintaining the security of your private keypair.